# Scheme/Racket: How to add keyword to define-syntax-parser

Tags: parsing, syntax, scheme, racket, keyword

I can define syntax for `for` loop this way:

```
(require syntax/parse/define)
(define-syntax-parser myfor
  [(_ Binding Form1 ...)
   #'(for (Binding) Form1 ...)]
)

(myfor (I (range 0 10))
  (displayln I)
)
```

It works, but when I add keyword to it, it doesn't follow the condition in `#:break` keyword:

```
(require syntax/parse/define)
(define-syntax-parser myfor
  [(_ Binding #:break Break Form1 ...)
   #'(for (Binding) Form1 ...)]
)

(myfor (I (range 0 10))
  #:break (= I 5)
  (displayln I)
)
```

How to add keywords to `define-syntax-parser` the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Accepting `#:break` in the input as an optional keyword
2. Producing `#:break` in the output when necessary

There are three approaches: multi-branch, optional, and syntax-class.

#### Multi-branch

The easiest way to solve this is by having two branches in the syntax-parser. One branch with the keyword, another branch without.

Two branches means two patterns to match on input, and two templates to produce output.

```
(define-syntax-parser myfor
  [(_ Binding #:break Break Form1 ...)
   #'(for (Binding #:break Break) Form1 ...)]
  [(_ Binding Form1 ...)
   #'(for (Binding) Form1 ...)])
```

This is fairly simple and straightforward, but has the disadvantage that you're repeating yourself, specifying `for`, `Binding` and `Form1 ...` multiple times for each branch, and it gets more verbose if you add more keywords.

#### Optional and `~?`

Another way is by using `~optional` and `~seq` in the pattern to match input, while using `~?` and `~@` in the template to produce output.

```
(define-syntax-parser myfor
  [(_ Binding {~optional {~seq #:break Break}} Form1 ...)
   #'(for (Binding {~? {~@ #:break Break}}) Form1 ...)])
```

Notice how `~?` in the template is where `~optional` was in the pattern, while `~@` in the template is where `~seq` was in the pattern.

This strategy is best when there's a clear symmetry between the input pattern and the output template.

#### Syntax-class

```
(begin-for-syntax
  (define-splicing-syntax-class maybe-break-clause
    [pattern {~seq} #:with (out ...) '()]
    [pattern {~seq #:break Break} #:with (out ...) #'(#:break Break)]))

(define-syntax-parser myfor
  [(_ Binding mbc:maybe-break-clause Form1 ...)
   #'(for (Binding mbc.out ...) Form1 ...)])
```

This strategy is overkill in this case for `#:break`, but may become necessary if the keyword behavior is more complicated than simply passing a keyword if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how, I need to add ~optional and ~seq to the syntax:

```
(require syntax/parse/define)
(define-syntax-parser myfor
  [(_ Binding {~optional {~seq #:break Break} #:defaults [(Break #'#f)] } Form1 ...)
   #'(for (Binding #:break Break) Form1 ...)]
)

(myfor (I (range 0 10))
  #:break (= I 5)
  (displayln I)
)
```

Comment: Instead of using `#:defaults` with `null`, where you're using `null` as a boolean-like condition expression, I would recommend not defaulting to null, but instead using `~?` and `~@` in the template so that the `#:break Break` doesn't show up in the output unless it also showed up in the input

Comment: sorry, the defaults should be `[(Break #'#f)]` not #'null